# Visual Studio preprocessor only works if /P is set

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, c-preprocessor

I'm having an awkward problem in Visual Studio 2008. I'm trying to define a string-to-enum mapping using a config header (call it param_defines.h) file which looks something like this:

```
DEFINE_ITEM( A, BOOLEAN )
DEFINE_ITEM( B, INT )
DEFINE_ITEM( C, INT )
```

And so on. This is then referenced in a second header (enums.h) file:

```
enum ParamType
{
    BOOLEAN = 0,
    INT
};

enum Param
{
    UNKNOWN = -1
#define DEFINE_ITEM( NAME, TYPE ) ,NAME
#include "param_defines.h"
#undef DEFINE_ITEM
};
```

Then in a third (source) file I'm doing this:

```
#include "enums.h"
std::tr1::unordered_map<std::string, int> params;
#define DEFINE_ITEM( NAME, TYPE ) params[ #NAME ] = NAME
#include "param_defines.h"
#undef DEFINE_ITEM
```

When I compile the source file I a load of errors like:

```
error C2065: 'A': undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'B': undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'C': undeclared identifier
```

So something is going on with the preprocessor isn't quite doing what I want it to do.

The kicker is this. I set /P so I have some way of diagnosing what's going wrong. When I do this, the file compiles successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't compile at all. `/P` suppresses the compilation (the file is only preprocessed, at which point there is no syntax checking), just like `/c` suppresses the linking.

Since you didn't show us what the output actually looks like, I'm going to be guessing: you're missing semicolon at the end of `#define DEFINE_ITEM( NAME, TYPE ) params[ #NAME ] = NAME`, which leads to generated code looking like this:

```
params["foo"] = foo
params["bar"] = bar
// ...
```

Add the semicolon, and if that doesn't help, edit the question with more details.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise it suppressed the compilation as well.